# Is there a solution for value error in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Having value error in google sheet, within pivot table, calculated field. Using the formula
=SUM("Box Office Revenue ($)")/COUNT("Box Office Revenue ($)".

Comment: is Box Office Revenue ($) a named range or just a placeholder for range??

Answer (score 0):

sounds like average:

```
=AVERAGE(A2:A)
```